# Zend 1.12 change value of specific decorator in FormElement

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am rendering a very simple form with a table format. I first add the elements, to later set their basic decorators with the following:

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
        'Viewhelper',
        array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'td')),
        'Label',
        array(array('labelCell'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'td', 'align'=>'right')),
        array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'tr'))
    ));
```

Afterwards, I manipulate whatever group of elements (as desired) to set up different looks, like: group elements in a single row. To do this last one, the following is carried out:

```
$this->getElement($elementName)->setDecorators(array(
        'Viewhelper',
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'colspan' => $colspan)),
        'Label',
        array(array('labelCell' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'align' => 'right')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
    ));
```

As you see, I have to `setDecorators()` adding all of them (the default ones) again, so I can change the `'data'` decorator and add the attribute `"colspan"`.

My question would be: is it possible to access and change a single decorator **without** having to set all of the previous decorators the element had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to call:

```
$viewHelperDecorator = $this->getElement($elementName)->getDecorator('ViewHelper');
```

Then, this is like any other decorator (it is a decorator abstract) - so you can call

```
$viewHelperDecorator->setOption();
```

and set the change you'd like.